# Windows touchdisplay not recognised as touch in fabric.js/event.js

Tags: javascript, html, windows, touch, fabricjs

I'm working on a painting application with multitouch.
This should work on a 32" inch Intellitouch 2521". Unfortunately as expected it is not plug and play together with the Fabric.js which used event.js to catch the touch event.

If i write simple js with touchstart, touchstart and touchmove events these do work with multi touch. But if I try the event.js pinch, touch,... these do not.

Any Idea what could be the reason for this? I already wrote the whole application in expectation that it would just work as it would on a phone (On Mobile the touch functions does work). But with Windows it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using android on desktop for my installation.